# How does this iron shower drain work?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain, cast-iron

I'm redoing a shower drain. I can see this thing which looks like an iron flange, with an iron drain going into it? Is this thing that looks like a flange removable? Is the drain inside the flange removable?

I'm looking to rebuild my shower, and I believe these need weep holes so the water can drain from the mortar bed into the drain. I don't see weep holes here. Should I use this drain? Or should I remove it? If so, how do you remove it?

[image: Top-down picture of drain]
[image: Side profile of drain]

Comment: what are you talking about `weep holes so the water can drain in the mortar bed`

Comment: @Ruskes typo "so the water can drain from the mortar bed into the drain"